# Can a window.scroll(function() prevent other code inside the document.ready(function() from rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I leave out the hover-function the window-scroll works just fine. As soon as I add other functions, it doesn't and the other way around. Without the window-scroll-function the other functions like the hover-function in this example seem to work. Why is that? I tried to call the document.ready-function multiple times. Didn't work… Someone please help! Thanks alot!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 120) {
   $('nav').addClass('shrink'); 
  }
  else {
   $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
 });

 $('.navpoints').hover(function(){
   $(this).css("font-weight":"500");
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, your `.css` function call is incorrect. Should be `$(this).css({'font-weight':'500'})` or `$(this).css('font-weight', '500')` - your choice.

Comment: Can't believe, I missed it! Thanks!!